# Authenticate user without login for web api using microsoft graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to use microsoft graph in web api which is using .net core 2.0, I want to authenticate user without login prompt.

Following is the code I have used, Please correct me if my method is wrong.

```
    string clientId = "";
    string clientsecret = "";
    string tenant = "";
    string resourceURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

    string userMail = "testuser3@company.com";
    public async Task<string> GetMyEmailUser()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = "";


            string AzureADAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/companyname.com";

            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AzureADAuthority, false);


            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientsecret);


            var authenticationResult =  authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURL, credential).Result;
           var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;


            using (var confClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
                confClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            confClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            confClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            confClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

               var response = confClient.GetAsync(url + "/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false&$top=100").Result;

                var jsonString = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                 IUserMessagesCollectionPage myDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IUserMessagesCollectionPage>(jsonString["value"].ToString());
            }
```

I am new to microsoft graph and would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Well, why do you not want the login prompt? Typically this means you are doing something against the philosophy of authentication in AAD.

Comment: I want to use the web api to check emails and forward it to a different user if any unread emails are found, and this web api will run every 2 mins. Hence logging is not feasible.

Comment: So it is what is called a *daemon application*. You can use application permissions to give it access to everyone's emails, or use a different kind of flow to get a refresh token for a single user, which can then be used later to get access tokens.

Comment: I have given access by registering the application on (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). I do get token from the above code, but when I use it to access messages, I get bad request error(400). I even tried using-                                                                                              var response = confClient.GetAsync(url + "/users/testuser3@companyname.com/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false&$top=100").Result;

Comment: Can you confirm that the token you received works for a less privileged request, like fetching the current user's profile "users/<user id>"?

Comment: You can't use ADAL with an app registered in the new app portal. You have to use MSAL.

Comment: @DmitryPimenov I tried doing that, and I get StatusCode-401, Reason-Unauthorized, Under microsoft graph permissions I have set permissions for contacts.read, user.Read and profile under delegated permissions and 
 under application permissions.

Comment: @juunas I would really appreciate if you could guide me as I am new

Comment: This example will help you I think: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2/blob/master/UserSync/Controllers/SyncController.cs

Comment: @juunas - the example that you have mentioned also challenges user to enter their credentials. Is there a way to bypass the challenge screen?

Comment: @Swapnil - Did you find how to get this working?