# Authenticate Azure AD user using graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to authenticate user against Azure AD using a web API.We are trying build a SPA and native app for iOS, we are trying to have the API take care of the authentication for us.I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171865/authenticate-user-without-login-for-web-api-using-microsoft-graph) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943391/authenticate-a-user-on-azure-ad-b2c-using-graph-api) and understood that its not possible.
**I just want to find out if there is any work around for my scenario.**
**This question is not a duplicate**

Comment: The proper way to do this use an authentication flow where the user authenticates against AAD in a webview in the mobile app and with a redirect/popup in the SPA. Your app handling user passwords is not the way federated authentication is supposed to work.

Comment: Plugging using the device's browser over WebView. There are significant SSO improvements (shared cookies across apps/web apps on the device). In iOS, this is `AuthenticationSession`, `SafariViewController` most recently (different per iOS version). MSAL will do this for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juunas is correct. You want to use something like ADAL to allow the user to authenticate against AAD for access to the Graph API and then use that auth token to access the graph. Microsoft has [an example which may be useful to you over here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-ios). It's written in objective C, but there are [other SPA examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa) out there if you search for ADAL, SPA,  and Graph API.

Comment: I'll drop a plug for MSAL, the newer client Auth library for signing in/getting access Azure AD (and the only library that supports B2C). Here's a few code samples: [Azure AD SPA](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2), [Azure AD B2C SPA](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp), [Azure AD iOS](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2)